# Функция system не может перейти в директорию system32/OpenSSH

Tags: c++, windows

Мне нужно запустить файл ssh-keygen.exe который находиться директории C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH
Но после того как я перехожу в папку system32 функция system в с++ не видит папку OpenSSH

```
system("cd C:\\Windows\\System32\\OpenSSH && dir")
```

Выводит такое сообщение The system cannot find the path specified.

Comment: ¿Приложение 64-битное? Может работает wow64 перенаправление.

Comment: Захардкоженные в программу пути могут сыграть с вами злую шутку, если программу будут переносить с машины на машину, и Windows окажется не там, где вы ее хотите найти.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Wow64DisableWow64FsRedirection
```

Я выключил перенаправление wow64, теперь всё работает.
Спасибо user7860670

Comment: От использования этой функции [больше вреда](https://blog.not-a-kernel-guy.com/2009/04/03/482/), чем пользы